# IntelliJ cannot resolve FXML Tags

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, fxml

Tags `padding` and `font` are unresolved by IntelliJ in my JavaFX project. Everything else works fine.
Plus, these were tags generated by FX-Scene-builder; so I really don't see why there's a problem. 
I have all the necessary imports too.

Here is my fxml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<fx:root maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"     minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="760.0" prefWidth="880.0" type="BorderPane"     xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"      fx:controller="testerl.Controller">
   <top>
  <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="99.0" prefWidth="900.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <children>
        <MenuBar>
          <menus>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
          </menus>
        </MenuBar>
        <ToolBar prefHeight="67.0" prefWidth="900.0">
          <items>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="67.0" text="Record" textFill="RED" />
              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="106.0" text="New Module" textFill="#0cc305" />
          </items>
        </ToolBar>
     </children>
  </VBox>
   </top>
   <center>
  <TextArea prefHeight="449.0" prefWidth="900.0" text="- c(module.erl)." wrapText="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <font>
        <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
     </font>
     <BorderPane.margin>
        <Insets />
     </BorderPane.margin>
     <padding>
        <Insets top="10.0" />
     </padding></TextArea>
   </center>
   <bottom>
  <TextArea opacity="0.5" prefHeight="66.0" prefWidth="900.0" promptText="TestErl Log:" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </bottom>
   <left>
  <ListView prefHeight="595.0" prefWidth="35.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </left>
    </fx:root>
```

Comment: Why doesn't anyone answer me anymore... lol

Comment: do you have `jfxrt.jar` library in your classpath?

Comment: Yes I do. ttttt

Comment: I added your code and haven't got any error, everything is resolvable. What is your JDK version?

Comment: 1.8.0_77 is the JRE version.

Comment: 1.7.0_79 is the SDK version

Comment: try to use different namespace: `xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"` instead of `xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"`.

Comment: Also read this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995989/problems-running-javafx-application-on-java-1-7u80

Comment: ayyy... still no luck; infact now IntelliJ is telling me to use different namespace to.

Comment: Well maybe also try to install JDK 8 and use it, because it is recommended with JavaFX 2.

Comment: hmmm.. ill try to download sdk 8.0 then.

Comment: Works! Thanks alot DimaSam.

Comment: glad to hear, you are welcome.